# configure command line tool not found in the Qt directory (Linux 32-bit)

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I have problem finding the configure command line tool. I downloaded Qt online installer for Linux 32-bit and it seems that the configure tool is not included. I have looked inside the Qt main directory. Does anyone have any idea where to find it or how to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tool is a part of Qt source code and is only useful when you're going to build Qt yourself. In that case, you shouldn't be downloading any installers; download the source code archive instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `build-essential` meta package to get a complete build environment for Ubuntu.